# How to specify port when using ssl with IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-express

working with vs2012, .net 4.5, mvc4.  my project has parts that are under ssl.
I am running my project under IIS Express. in project properties:

```
>SSL Enabled: True
>SSL Url: https://localhost:44300/
>URL: http://localhost:18000/
```

The project runs fine. if you hit F5, the browser opens with the site at `>http://localhost:18000/` 
and all the regular (http) pages works fine.
but if you hit the link to the login page, for example, which is ssl protected, ([RequireHttps] in the controller), it tries to go to

```
>https://localhost/Account/LogOn
```

which is not correct, and hence fails on 404.
if you go manually to

```
>https://localhost:44300/Account/LogOn
```

the login page works fine.
the question is: how to cause the thing to go to the correct address when https is required?

Answer (score 1):

Configure your web.config file with a rewrite tag like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Secure Account Controller" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^account" ignoreCase="true">
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{c:1}:44300{URL}"/>
      </match>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The above codes can be generated by IIS panel easily.

Comment: This should be added to `<system.webServer>` section? When I copy/paste the code and run the site, I get an 500.52 URL RewriteModule Error (Unrecognized element 'conditions'). I think the `<conditions>` isn't supposed to be nested inside the `<match>` tag.

Comment: Another "problem" is that after this, if you click on any of the links on the LogIn page, you continue using `https`. Maybe this is standard behavior, but I would like to use https only for the views of the Account controller.

Comment: yes. put it at <system.webServer>. also you must prepare url contents and controller actions via SSL. foreach controller action requires ssl put [RequireHttps] statement.